# How to retain only lowercase text and underscore in string and replace everything else with space?

Tags: python, regex

I need to retain only lowercase text and underscore in a string and replace everything else with space(" ").

say input: `text List ? this_word.` 
required output: `text  ist this_word`

I am trying the regex expression `^[a-z_]` but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: can you please provide some code you tried ??

Comment: Yes, re.sub("^[a-z_]", " ", string) but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: because you are only matching for a single character at the beginning of the string: `^[a-z_]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
[^a-z_\s]
```

Test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/AQvaYV/1)

```
import re

regex = r"[^a-z_\s]"

test_str = " text List ? this_word."

subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output:

```
 text ist  this_word
```

Test the code [here](https://tio.run/##NY7NSsRAEITv8xRFvOxCXAQ9CeLJw0L0pAfxJ0xibzKQzAw9Pbjx5WNPxD41XV91VVxkDP56Xd0cAwuYjGEa6Iw7cPX2aS9/2vf0URkjlKRNwipUEDoLGpcE95DRpfY78NdBqZQ7PSqi@wVeQ0ZvPWbrs52mBSlS706Legg@zx0xwklD42R7mslLQregH60fnB827EZGWB5yUbVaylP5z3TQqN1WtcaWWuO/Yo2ruhCPL83zsTk@PeyNcSWmmG8NdCI7L9j9nfbr@gs)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldn't it figure it out because I am only just learning regex.

Comment: Here is a really good start to learn Regex : [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions), and you can experiment on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/): they are challenges, a test editor, and a code generator for python if you need it

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "aBcDeFgH"
new_string = []

for char in string:
    if char.islower() or char == "_":
        new_string.append(char)
    else:
        new_string.append(" ")

print(''.join(new_string))
```

OUTPUT:

```
a c e g
```

Comment: It only needs to handle underscores, which I have already implemented.